# Do you have any idea why returned List items from Class not working?

Tags: c#, wpf

First of all English is not my native language and title is probably horrible so I appologize, and moderators feel free to edit title if you want.

I have method createGrpButtons in class Receipt, which instantiate class CreateGrpButtons, and use returned List to create buttons on form. If I use same code inside method it works, but when i move code into the class it stop working. List items are still passed(i can see them while debbuging), but buttons are not created.

```
 public class TodoItem
        {
            public string Content { get; set; }
            public string Margin { get; set; }
            public string Tag { get; set; }
            public int Height { get; set; }
            public int Width { get; set; }

        }

          private void createGrpButtons()
        {

            int stPanelHeight = (Convert.ToInt16(stPanel.ActualHeight));
            int stPanelWidth = (Convert.ToInt16(stPanel.ActualWidth));

            GenerateGrpButtons btnGenGrp = new GenerateGrpButtons();
            btnList.ItemsSource = btnGenGrp.CreateGrpButtons(70, 0, stPanelHeight, stPanelWidth);

        }
```

And here is createGrpButton Class

```
class GenerateGrpButtons:frmReceipt 
    {

            public List<TodoItem> CreateGrpButtons( int btnMinimumHeightSize, int separationY, int pnlHeight, int pnlWidth)
        {
            //Calculate size of container to determine numbers of button
            //int btnMinimumHeightSize = 40;
            //int separationY = 0; //separation between buttons

            int btnNumberCreated = (pnlHeight / btnMinimumHeightSize);

            List<TodoItem> btns = new List<TodoItem>();

            for (int i = 0; i < btnNumberCreated; i++)
            {
                if (i == btnNumberCreated - 1)
                {
                    var HeightTmp = (Convert.ToDouble(stPanel.ActualHeight)) - (btnMinimumHeightSize * i);
                    btns.Add(new TodoItem() { Content = "ˇˇˇˇ", Height = Convert.ToInt16(HeightTmp), Width = Convert.ToInt16(stPanel.ActualWidth), Tag = "LastGrp", Margin = "0,0,0,0" });
                }
                else
                {
                    btns.Add(new TodoItem() { Content = "Group " + i, Height = btnMinimumHeightSize, Width = Convert.ToInt16(stPanel.ActualWidth), Tag = "Grp" + Convert.ToString(i), Margin = "1," + separationY + ",0,0" });
                }
            }

            return btns;
         }
    }
```

When I debug here:

```
 btnList.ItemsSource = btnGenGrp.CreateGrpButtons(70, 0, stPanelHeight, stPanelWidth);
```

I can see that there are some number of items created, and i can see item properties, but buttons are not created on form.

However if i do this (everything in method), then buttons appear on the form.

```
    //Calculate size of container to determine numbers of button
    int btnMinimumHeightSize = 40;
    int separationY = 0; //separation between buttons

    int btnNumberCreated = ((Convert.ToInt16(stPanel.ActualHeight) / btnMinimumHeightSize));

    List<TodoItem> btns = new List<TodoItem>();

    for (int i = 0; i < btnNumberCreated; i++)
    {
        if (i == btnNumberCreated - 1)
        {
            var HeightTmp = (Convert.ToDouble(stPanel.ActualHeight)) - (btnMinimumHeightSize * i);
            btns.Add(new TodoItem() { Content = "ˇˇˇˇ", Height = Convert.ToInt16(HeightTmp), Width = Convert.ToInt16(stPanel.ActualWidth), Tag = "LastGrp", Margin = "0,0,0,0" });
        }
        else
        {
            btns.Add(new TodoItem() { Content = "Group " + i, Height = btnMinimumHeightSize, Width = Convert.ToInt16(stPanel.ActualWidth), Tag = "Grp" + Convert.ToString(i), Margin = "1," + separationY + ",0,0" });
        }
    }
    btnList.ItemsSource = btns;
```

Buttons are binded through this:

```
 <StackPanel  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="stPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <ItemsControl Name="btnList">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content ="{Binding Content}" Height="{Binding Height}" Width="{Binding Width}" Tag="{Binding Tag}" Margin="{Binding Margin}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Click="ClickHandlerGrp" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
```

Anybody have a clue on where did I messed up?

Comment: Ugh, this is an aweful lot of code! I think you should be able to find out WHERE exactly the problem is yourself and ask only about that specific part of your code.

Comment: @marsze At least it's not one of those *the button doesn't work* here's the code: *insert entire 900 line code file here*.

Comment: One thing I notice is that even though you pass `stPanelHeight` and `stPanelWidth` to the method, you still access `stPanel.ActualHeight` and `stPanel.ActualWidth` directly inside the method.

Comment: There is only one reason: btnList.ItemSources is reseted after setting

Comment: Sorry... In case when everything is in method buttons are drawn on form, in case when I am calling list from class(instantiate) buttons are not drawn, but returned list is the same(at least it looks the same to me). There are no errors, it just won't draw thos buttons.

Comment: @ C.Evenhuis Thank you! It was a bug and you squashed it. If you want, create answer so i can accept it. Buttons was created, but they where invisible since Height and Width was set to 0, since from some reason class wasn't accessing Form.

Comment: @Bodul did that, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the `stPanelHeight` and `stPanelWidth` values are correctly supplied to the method, the method still accesses `stPanel.ActualHeight` and `stPanel.ActualWidth` directly.